# COUNT(1) + COUNT(DISTINCT()) much slower then doing 2 queries separately

Tags: sql, sql-server, sqlperformance

Query explanation:

- `Person` (identified by `PersonID`) may have or not have a corresponding `Job` (identified by `JobID`).
- If there's a corresponding `Job`, binding is stored in table `PersonJob` (`PersonID` <=> `JobID`).
- `Person` without `Job` are ignored.
- `Job` also has `CityID`.
- Per every `Job.CityID`, query wants to know total count of `Person` and also count of unique `Person.HouseID`

Query:

```
SELECT
  Job.CityID, COUNT(1) NumTotal, COUNT(DISTINCT(Person.HouseID)) NumDistinct
FROM
  Job
  INNER JOIN PersonJob ON (PersonJob.JobID = Job.JobID)
  INNER JOIN Person ON (Person.PersonID = PersonJob.PersonID)
GROUP BY
  Job.CityID
```

Stats:

- `SELECT COUNT(1) FROM PersonJob` ~ 600.000
- `SELECT COUNT(1) FROM Person` ~ 800.000
- `SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(Person.HouseID)) FROM Person` ~ 10.000
- `SELECT COUNT(1) FROM Job` ~ 500
- MS SQL Server 10.50

Problem:

- `COUNT(1)` part of query, when run separately, runs in 0.25sec.

  ```
  SELECT
    Job.CityID, COUNT(1) NumTotal
  FROM
    Job
    INNER JOIN PersonJob ON (PersonJob.JobID = Job.JobID)
    INNER JOIN Person ON (Person.PersonID = PersonJob.PersonID)
  GROUP BY
    Job.CityID
  ```
- `COUNT(DISTINCT(Person.HouseID))` part of query, when run separately, runs in 0.80sec.

  ```
  SELECT
    Job.CityID, COUNT(DISTINCT(Person.HouseID)) NumDistinct
  FROM
    Job
    INNER JOIN PersonJob ON (PersonJob.JobID = Job.JobID)
    INNER JOIN Person ON (Person.PersonID = PersonJob.PersonID)
  GROUP BY
    Job.CityID
  ```
- Entire query runs in 3.10sec  - **3 times slower, why?**

Execution plans:

- I'm no expert in reading those, sorry.
- As far as I can tell, the problem lies within COUNT(DISTINCT)
- In partial query:

  - 25% Hash match (Aggregate) (output `Job.CityID`)
  - 15% Hash match (Inner Join) (output `Job.CityID`, `Person.HouseID`)

    - 30% Index scan (output `Person.PersonID`, `Person.HouseID`)
    - 14% Index seek (output `PersonJob.PersonID`)
- In full query:

  - 03% Hash match (Partial aggregate) (output `Job.CityID`, `COUNT(*)`)
  - 31% Hash match (Aggregate) (output `Job.CityID`)
  - 29% Table Spool (output `Job.CityID`, `Person.HouseID`)

Comment: Do your comparisons use the `join`s?

Comment: Not sure what you mean, probably partial queries? Added them.

Comment: Unrelated, but: `distinct` is ***NOT***  a function. `distinct (Person.HouseID)`  is **exactly** the same thing as `distinct Person.HouseID`

Comment: Compare the actual execution plans of your three queries and you should see where the difference is.

Comment: added execution plan details

Comment: [Distinct Aggregation Considered Harmful](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlqueryprocessing/2008/09/22/distinct-aggregation-considered-harmful/)

Comment: This article looks very promising! You should have posted it as an answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a known issue in versions of SQL Server prior to 2012.

You could try this rewrite based [on the code here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlqueryprocessing/2008/09/22/distinct-aggregation-considered-harmful/).

```
WITH T1
     AS (SELECT Job.CityID,
                Person.HouseID
         FROM   Job
                INNER JOIN PersonJob
                        ON ( PersonJob.JobID = Job.JobID )
                INNER JOIN Person
                        ON ( Person.PersonID = PersonJob.PersonID )),
     PartialSums
     AS (SELECT COUNT(*) AS CountStarPartialCount,
                HouseID,
                CityID
         FROM   T1
         GROUP  BY CityID,
                   HouseID)
SELECT CityID,
       SUM(CountStarPartialCount) AS NumTotal,
       COUNT(HouseID)             AS NumDistinct
FROM   PartialSums
GROUP  BY CityID
```

SQL Server 2012 has some improvements in this area. See [Is Distinct Aggregation Still Considered Harmful?](http://web.archive.org/web/20170606142356/http://sqlblog.com/blogs/paul_white/archive/2011/12/04/is-distinct-aggregation-still-considered-harmful.aspx)

Comment: Never thought about this peculiarity of the optimiser. I learned something new today. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks! At least I know it's the problem with MS SQL. I have posted my final decision as separate answer.

Answer (score 1):

After reading workaround provided by Martin Smith, I have decided the workaround is too difficult to read and understand and will become total mess should the need for additional DISTINCT column arise. I have decided to LEFT JOIN partial queries as follows:

```
SELECT
  Job.CityID, NumTotal.Value, NumDistinct.Value
FROM
  Job
  LEFT JOIN
  (
    SELECT
      Job.CityID, COUNT(1) AS Value
    FROM
      Job
      INNER JOIN PersonJob ON (PersonJob.JobID = Job.JobID)
      INNER JOIN Person ON (Person.PersonID = PersonJob.PersonID)
    GROUP BY
      Job.CityID
  ) NumTotal ON (NumTotal.CityID = Job.CityID)
  LEFT JOIN
  (
    SELECT
      Job.CityID, COUNT(DISTINCT Person.HouseID) AS Value
    FROM
      Job
      INNER JOIN PersonJob ON (PersonJob.JobID = Job.JobID)
      INNER JOIN Person ON (Person.PersonID = PersonJob.PersonID)
    GROUP BY
      Job.CityID
  ) NumDistinct ON (NumDistinct.CityID = Job.CityID)
GROUP BY
  Job.CityID
```

This runs in 0.70sec, while the "workaround" sql runs in 0.60sec. That means that LEFT JOIN'inig is 5x faster then "original full query" and only 20% slower then "workaround", while being much easier to read and extend.